# c# handle return value and execute code

Tags: c#, .net, optimization

there is some `code` to execute after validation.
consider a variable `SOQualityStandards = true;`

this variable is validated before the execution of code.
i have come across two ways of checking `SOQualityStandards`

one is

```
if(SOQualityStandards)
{
   //code to execute
}
```

and the other is

```
if(!SOQualityStandards)  return; 
//code to execute
```

is there any performance difference between both. which one should i consider.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They have the same semantics (assuming there is no other code in the function after the if-block in the first example).

I find the first to be clearer, but that is a matter of personal preference.

Answer (score 2):

The compiler will consider those two options to be the same and could transform one into the other or visa versa, so performance considerations are irrelivent. Even if performence were affected, I think the readability/maintainability is a larger issue in these questions anyway.

I tend to do the return at the beginning in cases like this, because it reduces the indentations and mental burden in reading the rest of the method. The states tested in returns at the beginning become states that no longer need to be considered in understanding the method. Large if blocks, on the other hand, require mentally tracking the state differences throughout the method.

This becomes especially important if there are several tests that need to be done to guard an interior block of code.

Answer (score 0):

There's no difference in the two approaches. It's a matter of personal choice.

Answer (score 0):

Choosing between the two is just personal preference (see [Sven's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6282731/1380710) and [bomslang's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6282763/1380710)). Micro-optimization is in most cases completely unnecessary.

You **shouldn't optimize execute-time until you see it's a problem**. You could be spending that valuable time to add other functionality or to come up with improvements to the system architecture.

In the case you actually need to optimize, **loops and recursive functions** are generally the first place to look.

If you would need further optimization than that, single line variable checks and manipulations would still be some of the last things to optimize.

Remember (as [Jeffrey said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6282802/1380710)) readability and maintainability are in most cases the most important factors.